# How can I duplicate a tag to insert after duplicated one?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a lot of tags, each tag with all same classname is long and including other tag, so I have simplified it as below

```
HTML = '''
<p class=test>111</p>
<p class=test>222</p>
<p class=test>333</p>
<p class=test>444</p>
<p class=test>555</p>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(HTML, 'lxml')

origin_tag = soup.select('p.test')
print(len(origin_tag)) #result is 5
origin_tag.insert(1, origin_tag[1])
print(len(origin_tag)) #result is 6
print(soup)  # but don't work, nothing changed
```

what I expect to see is:

```
<p class=test>111</p>
<p class=test>222</p>
<p class=test>222</p>
<p class=test>333</p>
<p class=test>444</p>
<p class=test>555</p>
```

how do I duplcate a tag and insert it???

Answer (score 0):

You can use `insert_after` in combination with `copy`:

```py
import copy

origin_tag.insert_after(copy.copy(origin_tag))
```

This makes a copy of origin tag and inserts it after origin tag.